# Why are double quotes added at start/end of files?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

**Context**: I have an Excel worksheet with 120 rows or so that I need to create files with.

Data is structured as follows:
The A column contains destination file names
The B column has the corresponding data to be written in each file

Giving us the following general layout
[image: data file layout]

To get data from B column written in each A column named files, I wrote the following:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub writeExportedMsgToXML()

' wrote that tiny script not to have to copy pate 117 messages by hand to have ops put them back on Q

Dim currentRow As Integer

' modify to match your data row start and end

For currentRow = 2 To 11

    Dim messageID As String
    Dim messageitSelf As String
    
    messageID = Trim(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & currentRow))
    messageitSelf = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & currentRow)

    Dim subDirectory As String

    subDirectory = "xmls"

    Dim filePath As String

    filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & subDirectory & "\" & messageID & ".xml"
    MsgBox (messageitSelf) ' for test purpose

    Open filePath For Output As #1

    Write #1, messageitSelf

    Close #1
Next currentRow
End Sub
```

The script does mostly what is intended except, it encloses the file content between double quotes.

File content enclosed in double quotes:
[image]

So, in a case where a file named F1.xml should just contain `<foo><bar>Baz</bar></foo>`

My script transforms it as `"<foo><bar>Baz</bar></foo>"`

**What I tried**

Replacing file writing part with the following

```vb
Dim objStream

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.Charset = "UTF-8"

Dim subDirectory As String

subDirectory = "xmls"

Dim filePath As String

filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & subDirectory & "\" & messageID & ".xml"

objStream.Open

objStream.WriteText messageitSelf

objStream.SaveToFile filePath

objStream.Close
```

With same outcome.

Should I declare `messageitSelf` as a different type?

Comment: `Write#` statements are what's putting string delimiters (it's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/writestatement) as such) - using a `Print#` statement instead should work. That said, consider declaring row numbers `As Long`, even if you have less than 32,768 rows to look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Write#` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/writestatement) surround strings with double quotes:

> Unlike the Print # statement, the Write # statement inserts commas between items **and quotation marks around strings** as they are written to the file.

Use `Print#` instead:

```vb
Dim fn As Long
fn = VBA.FreeFile

Open filePath For Output As #fn
Print #fn, messageitSelf
Close #fn
```

Comment: Thank you Mathieu for the precisions. It did the trick :)
Saved me hours of work